# Add labels to points based on variable names

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have a list of points, and from them I am drawing a polygon:

```
pts = {AA,BB,CC,DD,EE} = 
 Table[{Cos[2 Pi*(i - 1)/5], Sin[2 Pi*(i - 1)/5]}, {i, 1, 5}]

Graphics[Join[
  {EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[], Polygon [pts]}, \
   {pts /. {x_, y_} :> {Blue, PointSize[0.01], Point[{x, y}]}}
  ]]
```

Now, I want to display the names of the points, based on the variable names (AA, BB, etc). Ideally, I am looking for a solution which would work given any list of variable names.

Comment: Launch `nm=Names["Global'*"]` after your assignment of `pts`. It will give you the list of all variables in kernel. Just remove the inner labels and use the rest of them as you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

names = {"AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"};

pts = Evaluate[ToExpression@names] = 
   Table[{Cos[2 Pi*(i - 1)/5], Sin[2 Pi*(i - 1)/5]}, {i, 1, 5}];

Graphics[{EdgeForm@{Thin, Black}, FaceForm[],
  Polygon@pts,
  Text[#[[1]], #[[2]], -1.5 Sign@#[[2]]] & /@
   Transpose@{names, pts},
  Blue, PointSize@0.01, Point@pts}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Note that you could generate the points using [`CirclePoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html)

```
pts === CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 5]

(* True *)
```

Comment: This was a neat trick. Instead of trying to convert variables to strings - start from a list of strings. Thanks!